# iOS - show Master View Controller with swipe in portrait

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, swipe, portrait

In a split view controller I would like to present the Master View Controller in portrait with a swipe gesture.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: A swipe from the edge should do that by default...

Comment: I thought so too, but it simply pops the current VC, since it belongs to a navigation controller hierarchy.

Comment: If you would show your source code excerpt instantiating the controllers, the things would get much easier.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question but I'm using this to present with gesture

```
 self.splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = YES;
```